# One Master Page deployed across all Site Collections SP2016

Tags: 2016, master-page, site-definition

My client has ~180 site collections in their SP2010 farm and are upgrading to SharePoint 2016. They want a solution where they build a single Master Page (based on Seattle) and then deploy it (and select it) for every site collection. This is doable (one option is creating each site collection using a site definition), but then they want to have some mechanism where each time the Master Page is updated, they want the changes to apply to every site collection.

I am thinking a code-based solution, but is there a simpler way? Can you have a web-application based Master Page that a Site Collection refers to, or must the Master Page reside in the Master Page Gallery? Earlier questions in this forum refer to earlier versions of SharePoint.

Comment: Please refer this [Can I use the same master page between Site Collections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/can-i-use-the-same-master-page-between-site-collections)

Comment: Thank you. That is a code based solution, and I would have to activate the feature in every site collection every time I made a change. It doesn't actually address my problem.

Comment: MasterPages are deployed at site collection scope. So, I don't think there will be any way to achieve this other than a code-based solution (powershell/c#)